# Eclipse and Yosemite

Tags: eclipse

I just upgraded to Yosemite and now the save process is extremely slow.  What used to take a second or two is now approaching a minute, and sometimes it doesn't save at all.  I've upgraded to the latest jdk, and reset my jre location, so everything should be ok.  It's hanging on "invoking Force.com builder" and taking a long time.  Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 2):

No worries, the saves seem pretty slow at the moment, that really depends on the Salesforce servers. I do saves with Mavensmate on both Mac OS X (Yosemite) and Windows, and I have the same problem.

Unfortunately this happens form time to time, perhaps too much salesforce server load or something. Nothing really you can do about it.

Comment: You may be right.  I'm using a different machine running Mavericks this morning, and getting the same behavior.  What took a couple seconds last week is taking 30sec /3min+ right now.  Maybe coincidence with my Yosemite install, but something sure has dramatically changed save times.

Comment: cs9, in particular, has been notoriously slow (but apparently undocumented/indicated). I'm sure it's just transient, as many organizations time their releases to salesforce.com releases to take advantage of new features, etc.

Comment: we've had the same problems with cs8 and cs18 so I think it's some kind of performance issue.